# CSS3 - Having issues with Flex wrap on iOS 10.3.2 (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

Before you refer me to other questions like mine, I have already looked through them, tried their solutions and they are not working for me.

My issue lies with the flexbox layout. I'm using the flexbox layout for some elements on my site.

I'm using `flex-wrap: wrap` and this works fine in my desktop testing environment, but when I try to test it on a mobile the device, the flex items are not wrapping and they all appear on the same line.

```css
.flexContainer {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
       -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
    /*    justify-content: space-around;*/
    }
    .flexContainerBox {
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        border-top: 20px solid transparent;
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px;
        max-width: 100%;
        font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
    }
    

   

 .flexContainerBoxBorderRight {
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      bottom: 25%;
      right: 0;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 566px){
        
        .flexContainerBoxBorderRight {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    
    
    .flexContainerBox1 {
        border-top-color: #15AF04;
        color: #15AF04
    }
    
    .flexContainerBox2 {
        border-top-color:#E4A621;
        color: #E4A621;
    }
    .flexContainerBox3 {
        border-top-color: #1b63b1;
        color: #1b63b1;
    }
    .flexContainerBox4 {
        border-top-color: #dd0000;
        color: #dd0000;
    
    }
    .flexContainerBox::before { 
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
    /*    border: 15px solid transparent;*/
        border-width:  0 15px 0 15px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
        transition: all .3s ease-out;
        }
    
    .flexContainerBox:hover::before {
      border-width: 15px 15px 0 15px;
    }
    
    .flexContainerBox1:hover::before { 
        border-top-color: #15AF04;
    
    }      
    .flexContainerBox2:hover::before { 
        border-top-color: #E4A621;
    }   
    .flexContainerBox3:hover::before { 
        border-top-color: #1b63b1;
    } 
    .flexContainerBox4:hover::before { 
        border-top-color: #dd0000;
    } 
    .flexContainerBoxTextBox > ul {
        list-style:none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .flexContainerBoxTextBox > ul > li{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .flexContainerBoxTextBox ul li + li::before{
        background-color: #ccc;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 1px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: -7px;
        left: 0;
        width: 22px;
    }
    
    .flexContainerBoxTextBox  {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-family: "museo";
    
    }
    
    .flexContainerBoxHeading {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.9em;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="indexContainer whiteContainer flexContainer">
            <div class="flexContainerBox flexContainerBox1">
                <div class="flexContainerBoxBorderRight"></div>
                    <div class="flexContainerBoxHeading">
                        WORLD CLASS <span style="color:#111"><br>FACILITIES</span>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="flexContainerBoxTextBox">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Day & Boarding</li>
                            <li>Secondary & Primary</li>
                            <li>Ages 2 to 18</li>
                            <li>200 Students </li>
                            <li>Cambridge IGCSE & GCEs</li>
                            <li>Beautiful sports facilities</li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexContainerBox flexContainerBox2">
                <div class="flexContainerBoxBorderRight"></div>
                <div class="flexContainerBoxHeading">
                        QUALITY <span style="color:#111"><br>EDUCATION</span>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="flexContainerBoxTextBox">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Over 10 Years Experience in Quality delivery</li>
                            <li>Good resources for Students</li>
                            <li>Student Oriented Learning</li>
                            <li>Good Teaching staff </li>
                            <li>Conducive Environment</li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexContainerBox flexContainerBox3">
                <div class="flexContainerBoxBorderRight"></div>
                <div class="flexContainerBoxHeading">
                        PERSONAL <span style="color:#111"><br>TOUCH</span>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="flexContainerBoxTextBox">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Small Class Sizes</li>
                            <li>Low teacher:student Ratio</li>
                            <li>Maximum contact with teachers</li>
                            <li>Mentorship programs</li>
                            <li>Student Counselling</li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexContainerBox flexContainerBox4">
                <div class="flexContainerBoxBorderRight"></div>
                <div class="flexContainerBoxHeading">
                        HOLISTIC <span style="color:#111"><br>APPROACH</span>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="flexContainerBoxTextBox">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Innovative Teaching Methods</li>
                            <li>Use of Technology in learning</li>
                            <li>Developing the "whole" child</li>
                            <li>Nurturing Talents & Gifts</li>
                            <li>Extra-curricular program</li>
                            <li>Christ-Centered School</li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The JSfiddle works as expected on a simulated iPhone 6.

Comment: Is it simulated from a computer? Even for me, it works perfectly when I simulate it but it only gives me issues when I try it on an actual phone. I wish I had an android to test it with so I could see if it's an issue with mobile devices or if it's just iOS.

Comment: Yeah, I used Chrome simulator. I don't have an iPhone, so I can't check it there. I can check it on my Android later, but someone else will probably get to it by then.

Comment: Yeah the guy down below found a fix. I'll have to test it on different devices and tablets but it's now working as intended on iOS. Thank you so much for your time. :)

Comment: Ok, let me know if you'd like me to test anything later on!

Comment: One more thing I just noticed ─ you don't need to prefix `flex` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the  tag:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Hey, I've already added that to my <head> section. Any other solution?

Comment: I'm not certain, but have you tried changing the flex direction to column using media queries?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Oh hey, that works. I've added

 @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    
    .flexContainer {
         -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

And it works out well for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I see you solved this, but the problem also lies with `flex-basis`. Without specifying the property, shorthand `flex: 1` will set it to 0%. Since your items don't have a set `width`, it falls back to the computed width of the item’s contents.

This means your current items will shrink to 0%. If you wanted a solution that doesn't require a media query, changing `.flexContainerBox` from `flex: 1` to `flex: 1 1 auto` will scale the wrapping correctly on iOS.

This sets your flex-basis, or "the amount of flexing a flex item can have", to scale automatically with your content.

Comment: I had tried this before. The issue I had with setting the flex item automatically was that, at certain screen widths, some divs would be larger than others. This screenshot illustrates that http://i.imgur.com/WRbEAnO.png

Comment: What about setting the item's `width`? That way the item has a minimum width to flex before breaking. Setting the width to ~300px, and flex-basis to auto gets rid of the irregular sizes.